# Request for VM in remote execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, automated-tests

I have my automation suite set-up. But now I want to set-up virtual machine for remote execution. I am beginner in automation and as far I know, remote execution is done so that the automation suite can be integrated with ci/cd pipeline and everyone can access it. For that matter, virtual machine is required so that hub and nodes could be set-up in remote for parallel executions.

Please correct me if any of the information above is incorrect.
Secondly, I have to request for a VM for that purpose. So what should be the size of the VM to be requested.

How do I set-up the remote execution in VM and how do I integrate that in my automation suite and pipeline.

Though there are a lot of different articles in Google. I wanted someone to truly guide me in remote execution.

Thank you in advance.

First I need to know the size of the VM to be requested.

Comment: Depends on your build system and the CI / CD pipeline and tools used. Just pick any size of VM and try it, then adjust until it's a good size. Also check the [tour], your question is not a good fit for stackoverflow, as it leaves too much room for guesswork and opinion.

Comment: Also, could you please tell me VM size for start?